# Transferring data from Elasticsearch to MongoDB

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, elasticsearch, laravel-9

I want to transfer data from Elasticsearch to MongoDB using Laravel commands. I know I'll be using `json_encode` and `json_decode`, but I don't know how to structure this entire process.

I copied the data from Elasticsearch, later assigned it to a variable in Laravel, changed the format using `json_encode`, and then transferred it to MongoDB. However, this approach doesn't seem very efficient to me, especially for large datasets.

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this? And how frequent you need this? Or do you want to migrate to MongoDB Atlas Search? 
In the case of a full migration and remove elasticsearch, it really doesn't matter how you do it, because it's only done once.  To enhance performance, you could also use bulk queries and/or bulk insert/updates.
You might even connect mongodb directly to your elasticsearch or through events or logstash.  But the best choice depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: "Could you enlighten me about directly connecting MongoDB to Elasticsearch? My goal is to perform queries on the data without affecting my live website. Therefore, I plan to transfer all the data to MongoDB in one go, but I also want to experiment with Elasticsearch occasionally and later transfer the data to MongoDB. Can you help me with this?"

Comment: Are you having performance issues with elasticsearch right now? Or are your queries so complex it's not possible with elasticsearch? Is elasticsearch the source of your data?  We are running thousand of complex queries on elasticsearch on several 3 node clusters (log data and catalog data) without any issues.  If you don't want to query your production index directly, you can use the `reindex` api to copy your data from one index to another first and query on that. 
I know you can connect mongodb to elasticsearch "directly" while using mongodb as a source, not a target.

Comment: I will try using the reindex API, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Keep in mind that using the reindex api, it will duplicate your data. So make sure you have enough storage available.  We stumbled upon that once.